# AWS Api Gateway Primitive Type in URL passed to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I have a setup where we use API gateway, a json mapping template in the integration request where we access URL parameters as such:

```
    "input":{
        "my_int":"$input.params('someurlparam')"
    },
```

I then access this variable in my Python lambda. This all works but I am getting inconsistent results in my lambda, sometimes the param is detected as an int and sometimes as a string. Different applications/testers accessing the api are getting different results and I have had to implement `isinstance(my_int, str)` checks and conversions in my lambda (I want to avoid this). How can I ensure the variable is parsed as an int prior to hitting my lambda?